# Why is puppet server was running fine but failing after some time fails?

Tags: puppet, devops

When I logged in to my VM (Ubuntu 18.04) for second time, its showing error:

```sh
# systemctl status puppetserver.service

puppetserver.service - puppetserver Service    Loaded: loaded
(/lib/systemd/system/puppetserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

**Active**: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-10-02 11:42:52 UTC; 2min 31s ago

Process: 23034 
ExecStart=/opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/bin/puppetserver
start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 02 11:42:52 puppet-master systemd[1]: puppetserver.service:
Control process exited, code=exited status=1 Oct 02 11:42:52
puppet-master systemd[1]: puppetserver.service: Failed with result
'exit-code'. Oct 02 11:42:52 puppet-master systemd[1]: Failed to start
puppetserver Service. Oct 02 11:42:52 puppet-master systemd[1]:
puppetserver.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 02 11:42:52 puppet-master systemd[1]: puppetserver.service:
Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5. Oct 02 11:42:52
puppet-master systemd[1]: Stopped puppetserver Service. Oct 02
11:42:52 puppet-master systemd[1]: puppetserver.service: Start request
repeated too quickly. Oct 02 11:42:52 puppet-master systemd[1]:
puppetserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. Oct 02 11:42:52
puppet-master systemd[1]: Failed to start puppetserver Service.
```

Is there a way to identify the issue?

Comment: You can receive better assistance with this on Super User or Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot more, you can run:

```sh
journalctl -xe -u puppetserver
```

And also check the `/var/log/puppetlabs/puppetserver/puppetserver.log` file for more info, but based on the error message:

```
Start request repeated too quickly
```

It seems that you didn't have patience to restart (as it can take few minutes).

The best to restart I recommend to you:

```sh
systemctl restart puppet*
systemctl restart puppet pxp-agent
```

In this way, the services manage the dependency between all `puppet*` services.

*Note:* [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), part of [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com) (includes [Stack Overflow](/tour)) provides support for [managing information technology systems in a business environment](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).